# Local dictionary variable unexpectedly persists beyond function

Tags: python-3.x

```
def do_something(id, some_dict={}):
    some_dict[id] = 1
    print(list(some_dict.keys()))

do_something(1) # prints [1]
# print(some_dict) # this gives an error (as expected)
do_something(2) # prints [1, 2] -- but why?
```

I have a sample function here that shows the unexpected behaviour of `do_something(2)` printing `[1,2]`. Both functions don't pass in the optional argument `some_dict`, so I expect that `some_dict` is initialised to be an empty dictionary `{}` at the start of every function call.

Even if that is not the case (why would it not be however?), I would have expected `some_dict` to be a local variable, and it shouldn't be existing in the namespace after the function ends. I verified this by attempting to `print(some_dict)` and it expectedly raised an error.

In that case, why do the keys from `some_dict` persist from the first function to the second? Answers to this strange phenomenon (to me) would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Python’s default arguments are **evaluated once when the function is
> defined, not each time the function is called**. This means that if you use a mutable default argument(in your case it is a `dict`) and
> mutate it, you will and have **mutated that object for all future calls**
> to the function as well.

https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments